# Xamarin build fails with an unknown error

Tags: xamarin, build-error

I installed Xamarin and was attempting to compile and run an empty app, but the compilation fails with an unknown error:
[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please add some info on your errors. In the second screenshot you have posted, you see "An error occurred. See full exception on logs for more details". Please take a look, and if you don't figure it out, post the details.

Comment: @ALI-KH-Y Please refer this [KB article](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1675684) to get the logs.

Comment: https://dotblogs.com.tw/wuanunet/2016/04/03/unable-to-create-new-blank-app-android-in-visual-studio-2015-xamarin It is a blog post in Chinese, but Google Translate should give you enough info. Unless you have Android SDK and NDK installed to the default location, it would fail miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Xamarin Android Player and select it from the devices list instead of Nexus 10 Android 3.0

[Download link](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player), [Installation guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/)